How many islands has Vietnam militarized in the South China Sea, and how many has China?
The WSJ says that Vietnam is copying the Chinese strategy of militarizing islands in the South China Sea, but that it's lagging behind China in that department.
However, it doesn't give any numbers, and on a quick google search I can find how many islands each controls e.g. in Spratleys, but not how many are militarized.
I realize there is a qualitative aspect to militarization too, e.g. the clip says that Vietnam has yet to build a 3000m runway in those islands. Perhaps answers can touch on that as well.

Why not including other countries there as well. I don't know: Taiwan, Philippines, Indonesia, ... An overview of the total militarization in the South China Sea would be great.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: sure.

Whether the islands are within internationally recognised territorial waters and/or already recognised as part of national territory would also be relevant.

@PaulJohnson I thought the key point of the discussion was that China and apparently Vietnam as well are militarizing islands that are not internationally recognized to be part of their national territory. Military build ups within your own territory are a lot less newsworthy.

@quarague Yes exactly. But the question doesn't say that.

I’m suspecting a lot will come down to what counts as “militarizing”. Does putting some cameras count? Radar? Barracks that are normally unoccupied? Or does it have to be a full military base, similar to what the Americans did in Diego Garcia?

@JonathanReez: I'm not gonna do that level of prescriptivism. An answer that  X has x Diego Garcia style islands and Y has y with a barracks and a watch tower would be a fair answer.
